# SwiftUI: using RotationGesture with changeable blur effect

Tags: rotation, swiftui, gesture, blur, uiblureffect

I am trying to combine the RotationGesture with changeable blur effect. So if you turn the ocular right, you get the picture more sharp like in binoculars. Turn left, it will be blurred again. The code below is basically doing it, but not very smoothly. Have you any ideas to improve the effect?

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var blurring: CGFloat = 20
@State var sharping: CGFloat = 0
@State private var rotateState: Double = 0

var body: some View {

    ZStack {

        Image("cat")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .blur(radius: blurring)
            .clipShape(Circle())

        Image("ocular_rk2")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.rotateState))
            .gesture(RotationGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    self.rotateState = value.degrees
                    self.changeBlur()
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    self.rotateState = value.degrees
                    print(self.rotateState)
                }
            )

    }

}


func changeBlur() {
    switch rotateState {
    case -10000...10000: sharping = 0.1

    default:
        print("# Mistake in Switch")
    }

    if rotateState < 0 {
        blurring += sharping
    } else {
        blurring -= sharping
    }
 }

}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

check this out (i tested it, it works)

maybe you should think about changing some values because you have to rotate a while until you see the text.

by the way: it is always a good manner to post compilable reproducable code (we do not have your images)...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var blurring: CGFloat = 20
    @State var sharping: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var rotateState: Double = 0

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Text("cat")
           //     .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .background(Color.yellow)

            Text("ocular_rk2")
               // .resizable()
                .blur(radius: blurring)

                .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
                .background(Color.red)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.rotateState))
                .gesture(RotationGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        self.rotateState = value.degrees
                        self.changeBlur()
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    self.rotateState = value.degrees
                    print(self.rotateState)
                    }
            )

        }

    }


    func changeBlur() {
        switch rotateState {
        case -10000...10000: sharping = 0.1

        default:
            print("# Mistake in Switch")
        }

        if rotateState < 0 {
            blurring = blurring + sharping
        } else {
            blurring = blurring - sharping
            print(blurring)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Chris, as far as  can see, you just copied my code, having changed images to text. That is may be more polite for others, but it is not the answer to my question.

Comment: Roman, Just Test it and you will see, it works - which yours does not. If you cannot see the difference - and there is an important one - I cannot help you